# copy constructor error: the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function

Tags: c++, matrix, copy-constructor

im working with simple 2D array,but in my copy constructor i encounter a problem.
Here's a excerpt from my code:

```
//default constructor
Matrix::Matrix(int r, int c)
{
    rows = r;
    cols = c;
    mainArray = new int[rows*cols];
    array = new int *[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        array[i] = mainArray + (i*cols);
}
//at member
int& Matrix::at(int i, int j)
{
    return array[i][j];
}
//copy constructor 
Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix & obj)
{
    rows = obj.rows;
    cols = obj.cols;
    mainArray = new int[rows*cols];
    array = new int *[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        array[i] = mainArray + (i*cols);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < obj.rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < obj.cols; j++)
            at(i, j) =obj.at(i,j);//PROBLEM
    }
}
```

when im trying to assign `at(i,j)=obj.at(i,j)` i get this:
the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with  the member function

as far as i know, copy constructor is supposed to be passed by `(const class& obj)`.
 what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your copy constructor take a `const` parameter, and your method `Matrix::at` is not const.

I suggest you to do two versions of your `at` method, one const and one not :

```
// Use for assignement
int& Matrix::at(int i, int j)
{
    return array[i][j];
}

// Use for reading
int Matrix::at(int i, int j) const
{
    return array[i][j];
}
```

Your compiler should know in which case call which one without your help, depending if you are trying to modify or just read your instance :

```
Matrix matrix(4, 4);

matrix.at(1, 2) = 42; // Assignement method called
int i = matrix.at(1, 2); // Read method called
```

Comment: thanks. problem solved. just wondering what it exactly does when `const` , the one used for reading does.

Comment: put a `const` at the end of a method prototype forbid you to modify an attribute of your class, or call other not-const method. But it means that your method won't modify the instance, so it will allow you to call your method on const instances, like your copy constructor argument. So put it wherever you can, like on any getter.

Answer (score 0):

Realize two versions of `at` function, one `const` and one `non-const`.

```
int& Matrix::at(int i, int j)
{
    return array[i][j];
}

int Matrix::at(int i, int j) const
{
    return array[i][j];
}
```